# Service for locking apps is not working properly

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I'm new in android. I'm developing an app for locking other apps. This is my Service class. I could generate list of apps from android device, from there I can able to  select each apps for locking. After that MYService class is runnng. But my app is not locked for selected apps like what'sapp, facebook etc. It is always locking the current (developing) app. Can anyone help me what to do for locking selected apps like facebook ? Also at what time we have to call the Service class

```
public class MyService extends android.app.Service {  

    final class TheThread implements  Runnable{

        int serviceID ;
        TheThread(int serviceID){
            this.serviceID = serviceID;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            synchronized(this){

                try{
                    wait(10000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){

                }

            }

        }
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service started!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        instance = this;
        Thread thread = new Thread(new TheThread(startId));
        thread.start();

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        }

        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
        String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Activity .... : "+activityOnTop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(!activityOnTop.equals("com.package.name"))
        {
            Intent intent1 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent1);      
            Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            Intent lockIntent = new Intent(MyService.this, Lockscreen.class);
            lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            instance.startActivity(lockIntent);

        }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       return START_STICKY;

    }
```

Comment: I can directly able to access the apps like facebook. Lock screen activity is not displayed there.

Comment: Please anyone help me to resolve this problem. I'm completely blocked here. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should review the Android Security model. Basically you can't access other applications with a vanilla install. You are completely sandboxed.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

Comment: In other words: it is not possible to implement a "lock up service" for all apps without modifying the android-os-sourcecode. On a rooted android device you may implement this with the [xposed-framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) which is not maintained any more and which does not work on android6 and up.

Comment: What should I do for locking other apps.? How can I implement for locking other apps ?

Comment: You can't without a hacked Android distro. k3b was correct. You would need a modified OS.

Comment: How is it possible ?